# How to use project layout inside Library project in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android app in which I have included a library project, I am able to use the resources of library project (ie layouts, styles etc) inside my main project. But I want to use the resources of my main project inside my library project. Is there any way to do that? I am stuck at this problem for quite a time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create dummy resources inside your library project, and anything with the same name in the main project will override it.

Example:

**LibProject/res/values/strings.xml:**

```
<string name="greeting">Hello from Library Project</string>
```

**MainProject/res/values/strings.xml:**

```
<string name="greeting">Hello from App Project</string>
```

Then, wherever you use `R.string.greeting`, even in your library project, the value from the main project will be used.

From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html):

> The application itself has highest priority and its resources are
>   always used in preference to identical resource IDs defined in
>   libraries.